# Error message when trying to open blender

Tags: hardware, system

I have downloaded blender but an error comes up ...can't detect 3d graphics card...blender requires card with open GL 2.1

How do I get this driver?...I am on windows 10

Thanks

Comment: Please add details about your graphic card brand/model

Comment: Mobile Intel(R) 4 Series Express Chipset Family (Microsoft Corporation - WDDM 1.1)
SAMSUNG RV510 LAPTOP  WINDOWS 10........HELP!!  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Getting_Started#Downloading_OpenGL

In the contents, it has 2. Downloading OpenGL
The link varies by Operating System

Read your Graphics Card Vendor notes about openGL support.
For instance, NVIDIA has notes about openGL support here:
https://developer.nvidia.com/opengl-driver

Hope that helps.